# Python Tkinter 3d plots cannot pan or zoom

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter

I've been trying to include 2d/3d plots using matplotlib in my Python GUI application using TKinter and have had success with 2d plots, but not 3d plots.  My issue is that none of the 3d plots can be panned or zoomed, even though the buttons in the navigation pane have responded to button clicks.  Here is an example code demonstrating my issue:

```
import tkinter as tk

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
import numpy as np

root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

#uncomment as needed to demonstrate 2d/3d plot
#subplot_kw = {'projection':'3d'}
subplot_kw = {}
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=subplot_kw)
if len(subplot_kw) > 0:
    ax.plot(range(100), np.random.rand(100), np.random.rand(100))
else:
    ax.plot(range(100), np.random.rand(100))

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, frame)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, frame)
toolbar.update()

root.mainloop()
```

So when I plot 2d using the above code, pan/zoom work as expected.  When I changed the commented lines and use a 3d plot, pan/zoom don't work.  Am I missing something simple or is there a problem with 3d pan/zoom in tkinter with matplotlib?

Answer (score 1):

First, don't use pyplot to create the figure that you want to embedd in tkinter (or any other GUI), because having the same figure managed by pyplot as well as your custom GUI may lead to all kinds of problems. Using the `matplotlib.figure.Figure` (as shown in [the "Embedding in tk" example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk_sgskip.html)), would in this case have the additional benefit of emitting a warning about the problem:

> `UserWarning: Axes3D.figure.canvas is 'None', mouse rotation disabled. 
>       Set canvas then call Axes3D.mouse_init().`

This essenitally means that you need to either call `mouse_init()`, or simply create the 3D axes ***after*** setting the canvas. The latter is shown below.

```
import tkinter
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (
                                    FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.wm_title("Embedding in Tk")

fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)  # A tk.DrawingArea.
canvas.draw()

ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection="3d")
t = np.arange(0, 3, .01)
ax.plot(t, 2 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * t))

toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, root)
toolbar.update()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tkinter.TOP, fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=1)


tkinter.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks!  I did see the example code you listed and didn't understand why pyplot wasn't used, as in other examples that plot figures explicitly.  I'll update all plots in my gui to create Figure() objects directly instead of using pyplot.

Comment: Also, do you know why canvas.get_tk_widget().pack() is called twice?  I don't see an explanation in the example and I can't find one in the documentation.  I haven't noticed a difference with either one of the two lines commented out.

Comment: Yes, that's probably an oversight in the example. I edited my code above.