# Matplotlib 3D-plot is either not interactive or in an additional window when trying to embed in TkInter

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, spyder, tkinter-canvas

**I've updated my question:**

After unsuccesfully trying alot of Answers to similar problems from SO, i now hope someone can give me a hint on why this isn't working:

I'm trying to embed an interactive Matplotlib 3D-Plot into a TkInter window. What i'd like is a tk-window with a "Plot" button, that has the embedded, interactive graph on it, and no further windows.

Here is a minimum reproducible example:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import *

def plot():
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=[10,10], num="test")

    # create the Tkinter canvas
    # containing the Matplotlib figure
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master = window)  
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
    canvas.draw()
    
    # creating the Matplotlib toolbar
    toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, window)
    toolbar.update()

    # placing the toolbar on the Tkinter window
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
    
    ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
    ax.scatter(2,3,4)


window = tk.Tk()

# button that displays the plot
plot_button = tk.Button(master = window, command = plot, height = 2, width = 10, text = "Plot")

# place the button into the window
plot_button.pack()

# run the gui
window.mainloop()
```

I have now edited my code, so that ax = plt.axes(projection='3d') and ax.scatter(2,3,4) are both at the end of my function.

Now i have the plot in the tkinter window and it is interactive. However, i still get a new window created by matplotlib every time i press "Plot". I haven't found a way to disable this.

Im still pretty confused with whats going on here, hopefully someone can help me with this!

Comment: Your code works fine in my environment: Windows 7, Python 3.8.10, matplotlib 3.4.2.  No extra window shown, embedded plot is interactive.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54119999/python-tkinter-3d-plots-cannot-pan-or-zoom) suggests to create the axes AFTER the canvas. I tried it with your code and it worked nicely. Just put `ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')` and `ax.scatter(2,3,4)` at the end of your function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Tkinter 3d plots cannot pan or zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54119999/python-tkinter-3d-plots-cannot-pan-or-zoom)